# How style selected option with CSS without styling all the other options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-select

How can I apply a CSS background color to only the selected option?  If I apply a class to the select object, it styles all options.  If I apply the desired classes to the options, I can see the styling fine for all the options when the select box is expanded. But when the select box is collapsed, the styling for the selected option is gone.  I observe this behavior in the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox.

Here is some super basic example code.  Without the jQuery, the selected option always appears unstyled.  With the jQuery, once a "modified" option is selected, all options are styled as "modified".  I haven't been able to figure out a way around this...  Any ideas?

I do not want to change the styling of the options.  Only to be able to see the styling of any given option when it is selected without overriding the styling of the others.

```
<style>
  select.modified,
  option.modified{
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>

<select id="example">
  <option value="bird" class="modified">bird</option>
  <option value="cat">cat</option>
  <option value="dog" class="modified">dog</option>
</select>

<script>
  $('#example').on('change',function(){
    $(this).prop('class',$(this).find('option:selected').prop('class'));  
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Did you mean `option.modified`?

Comment: Browsers characteristically make it difficult to style elements such as checkboxes, radio buttons, and multi/selects. Generally, the work-around is to hide the actual form element and put a style-able, interactive `div` right next to it.

Comment: There are bugs in some browsers (namely chrome + linux) which makes `<option>` not inherit background from `<select>` so you should always (when setting a select background) set it for all options as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the best workaround for this issue.  Basically I have to remove any classes from the selected option on focus, and add it back those classes on blur.  This seems to do the trick fairly well.

```
<script>
  $('#example').on('change',function(){
    // do whatever needs to be done
    $(this).blur();
  }).on('focus',function(){
    $(this).removeClass($(this).find('option:selected').prop('class'));
  }).on('blur',function(){
    $(this).addClass($(this).find('option:selected').prop('class'));
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select option.modified { color: red; /*something*/ }
```

---

```
$('#example').on('change', function(){
    $(this).find('option').removeClass('modified');
    $(this).find('option:selected').addClass('modified');
});
```

Comment: LIke I said above, I don't want change styling of the options.  I just want to be able to see an option's styling when it is selected, which apparently Chrome and Firefox don't do.

Comment: @DouglasMauch: So use a different `class` for the default `option` styles and use `.modified` only for what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#example').on('change',function(){
   $(':selected', this).addClass('modified').siblings().removeClass('modified')
});
```

```
option.modified{
   background-color: red;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Qu5Xa/)

Comment: Ah, Good use of `.siblings()`. Never struck me when I needed it before!  +1!

Comment: I don't want to change the styling of the individual options.  That is set by something else at the time when the select box is rendered.  I only want to be able to see the styling of an option when it is selected, without essentially overriding the styling of all the other options.

Answer (score 0):

Your event is on the entire `selected#example` list so naturally all its options would get the background since they SIT on the select. Try tying your event to the option tags.

Also, Your 2nd rule applies the color to ALL option tags AND fictitious `modified` tags. By replacing the `,` with a `.` you'll do what you mean - only those options with the `modified` class.

Comment: the comma was a typo, it was supposed to be option.modifed in the CSS selector

Answer (score 0):

Well, after reading the comments I think you really want something along these lines.

```
$('#example').on('change', function() {
    console.log(this.options[this.selectedIndex].style);
});​
```

or without jQuery

```
document.getElementById('example').onchange = function() {
    console.log(this.options[this.selectedIndex].style);
};
```

this will give you a `CSSStyleDeclaration` of all of the current rules. Keep in mind hex values are returned as rgb.

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/Qu5Xa/1/

OR the other alternative is to return the className....

```
document.getElementById('example').onchange = function() {
    console.log(this.options[this.selectedIndex].className);
};
```

or jQuery

```
$('#example').on('change', function() {
    $(this.options[this.selectedIndex]).attr('class'); // however I would still not even bother wrapping this up in jQuery and just use this.options[this.selectedIndex].className
});​
```